# Save a photoshop file that opens multiple canvases?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Let's say I have multiple canvases/windows open and want them to all open up when the photoshop file is opened. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

In short, no.

Photoshop files don't include a 'savedState', not even on Mac where every other app does.

Comment: hmmm… downvote for telling it like it is. Interesting take on life. *"I wanted this to be possible, but it's not, so I shall punish the person who tells me it's not possible."*

Comment: Yes, strange indeed.